Regex searching with escaping
Given the following 3 lines
"unit": "mm"
"unit": "s"
"unit": "%"

If I do a regex search /"unit": "[^sm]", it would return "unit": "%".
However, for /"unit": "[^s%]" or /"unit": "[^s\%]", it didn't return "unit": "mm".
Why is that?

The collection [^s%] matches exactly one character that's not an 's' or a '%'. Put quotes around it and it will match one of the said character in quotes. And "mm" is two characters in quotes.
That's why.
This is documented in :help /[].
Remove the trailing quote and it will match "unit": "m
Or add a count like /"unit": "[^s%]\{1,2}" so it matches one or two characters. More generally, /"unit": "[^s%]*" to match no or any number of not s or % between quotes (as suggested by Barmar).
All these largely do the same and differ in details. It depends on what you want to achieve.
One more piece of advice: when constructing search patterns, :set incsearch is very useful. It will highlight matches as you type your pattern. If the highlight goes away, you know your last keystroke caused it and can backtrack. See :help 'incsearch'.

/me discards answer

@romainl your answer would have been much more elaborate and thorough, I am sure. And Vivian keeps on outracing me. It's a sting. I know.

Or [^s%]* to match any number (including 0) of "not s or %" between quotes.

@Barmar I thought it was obvious :-) OP may find it useful, I edited it in. Thank you.
